# Why does this UIScrollView experiment fail?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

In my view contoller's `viewDidLoad` function, I have this guy:

```
UIScrollView *scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
scroller.contentSize = self.view.frame.size; // Tried w/ and w/o this
scroller.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES; // Tried w/ and w/o this

for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, x * 100, 100, 100)];
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i label", x];
    [scroller addSubview:label];
}

[self.view addSubview:scroller];
```

It shows the first 8 labels OK, but the scroll view won't... scroll. It is just cut off. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't scroll because your `contentSize` is only set to the same size as the scrollview itself. The `contentSize` is the size of the scrollable area that the scrollview acts as a window in to. You need to set it wide enough to actually see your labels.

Based on your current code, your final label is in rect `{0, 900, 100, 100}`, so your `contentSize` needs to be at least `CGSizeMake(100, 1000)`.

Comment: Also helpful was setting the `contentSize` proportional to the number of objects I've added to it. Thanks!